# After 1st May, what are we'll do with jcenter() repository and what is it alternative?

Tags: flutter, maven, android-build, bintray, jcenter

We are recently notified by they permanently suspension:

https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

How we'll proceed with Android building runners? I use Flutter and i don't know which repository I'll transfer for that case.

Answer (score 3):

Flutter itself is moving away from JCenter to `mavenCentral()` [per this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/78812/files).

As you can see there, they're still pulling a few libraries from JCenter that weren't yet available in Maven Central. A [subsequent PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/80908/files) removed that after it was added to Maven Central.

Android Studio 4.2 RC suggests replacing any instance of `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`.